# react navigation theme header bug

Tags: react-navigation

First, change the theme of IOS to the light, access the app, and look at the header, and there is a border bottom style in the header.

However, if you change the theme to dark and look at the header, there is no border bottom.

IOS Dark Mode
[image]

IOS Light Mode
[image]

Is navigation related to the theme of the device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Example from @react-navigation documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/themes/#using-the-operating-system-preferences)

Using the operating system preferences​

On iOS 13+ and Android 10+, you can get user's preferred color scheme ('dark' or 'light') with the (Appearance API).

Try this example on Snack

```
import { useColorScheme } from 'react-native';
import {
  NavigationContainer,
  DefaultTheme,
  DarkTheme,
} from '@react-navigation/native';

export default () => {
  const scheme = useColorScheme();

  return (
    <NavigationContainer theme={scheme === 'dark' ? DarkTheme : DefaultTheme}>
      {/* content */}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

Comment: I tried this, but I still can't see the border bottom.

Comment: Ok, then try hide header border bottom in stack navigation https://reactnavigation.org/docs/elements/#headershadowvisible

Comment: I want the bottom line of the header to come out. By the way, are you telling me to hide it?

Comment: If you use @react-navigation/native-stack then she have bug. With this navigation we use library react-native-screens and in dark mode this library hide bottom border in header. [react-native-screens](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-screens/issues/728)
Best what you can do it's disabled dark mode for application, or just hide default header and create custom with shadow and border.

Comment: I just saw that my source code is using the native-stack library.

Could you tell me which library can replace @react-navigation/native-stack?

Comment: Yes https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/
This look like native-stack but have extra options

Comment: Does this allow you to see the bottom line of the header regardless of the instrument theme?